# JSRender using "this" variable inside loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsrender

I am passing an array `[2223,2344]` into a simple loop. Goal is something like:

```
{{for bookings}}
   {{this??}}
{{/for}}
```

In the past I have used {{:ID}} type references to refer to the objects properties but not sure how to reference the object inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

`{{for bookings}}
   {{:#data}}
{{/for}}`

See docs and sample here: http://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag.

and the sample here: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/paths - e.g. look at the template where it iterates over "phones".